# I want to add images on click of a button

Tags: android

I want to add images on click of a button, But the button should move to the next location and the image should get added there. I am able to achieve this by this code

```
b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i = new Intent(
                    Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

            startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


        }
    });


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
        Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                filePathColumn, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
        String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
        cursor.close();

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));

    }

}
```

The problem is, I want to add several images one by one. The image i add should stay there and other image should get added if the user wants to. I guess i will need a loop for this. Please help.

Comment: `But the button should move to the next location and the image should get added there.` What do you mean by this  ? Where you want to move button ?

Comment: Suppose I have a grid layout n images in that, and a button. If the user wants to add more images he can add on the button's click. The image will get added on place of the button. Again if he want to add an image he can do it, without replacing the image he added before.

Comment: That means you are trying to add the images on `GridView` dynamically which will contain the `Buttons` initially and on click of buttons the image will be added on that place and the button will be disappeared. Right ?

Comment: yea but except one thing, the button should not get disappeared.

Comment: Instead of a button you can use menu for that. Create a new menu with option 'Add Image'

Comment: And to put many images dynamically, You should use `GridView` with a custom adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using a GridView with custom adapter...try this approach:

1) create an initially empty array for images and a gridview with custom layout containing an imageview.

2) set getCount() method of gridview adapter as imageArray.length+1;

3) in getView() method, write a condition for checking the last position, and  replace your imageview source with button image there and also put this condition on onclicklistener for adding image to your array..

4) after adding image each time just refresh this adapter...

hope you get this...

Comment: can you provide me with an example?